# change twitter bootstrap carousel background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you change the Twitter Bootstrap 3 carousel background?

What I want is a standard red background. 
Then, each carousel image will be put on top of this red background.
Simply changing the  tag's css gives me the red background, but then carousel images don't show up.

```
@import url("bootstrap.min.css");

body {
  background-image:url('../images/red_background.png')
}
```

Comment: try background-color: red; so that you're not overwriting the background image declaration. Though I'm not sure what the body tag has to do with the carousel.

Comment: can you over-write `.carousel` in your style.css ?

Comment: also confirm the path to your image is correct... (i.e. is it really in `../images/`? (from where your page is)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to overwrite `.carousel` like this:

```
    .carousel {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/620x420/ff9900);
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;     /* Shows as a border around the carousel */
    }
```

The padding is there only to make the presence of the bg-colour obvious.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4W9j/1)**

Answer (score -1):

.carousel{
background-color: red
}